# How to make Android/iPhone app with redirect to website using Phonegap?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, redirect

I want to make a simple Android and iPhone application and show my website using Phonegap.

The following code does not work.

```
document.write(document.location.href);
```

Comment: This seems odd to me. Why not just make a simple cordova/phonegap application (which will work on iOS and android) and then have that app open an external link to your web page using [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin.

Comment: Fido can you build it for me?

Comment: No. Simply because stackoverflow is a question and answer platform. If you are having trouble building cordova applications locally then try building them remotely using [phonegap](https://build.phonegap.com/). Phonegap can also pull in plugins. [This](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_plugins.md.html) will show you how to import plugins on phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create a native application for both platforms which includes a full page webview that redirects to your website?

**Android**

- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <WebView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/webView" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- Main.java

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
      webView.loadUrl("YOUR_URL_HERE");
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks you!) I will try it